Select2 usage issue
my code
miku = [
        { id: 1, text: "Blue" },
        { id: 12, text: "David" },
        { id: 3, text: "Judy" },
        { id: 4, text: "Kate" },
        { id: 5, text: "John" },
    ];
    $(".search39").select2({
        language: 'zh-TW',
        placeholder: "第三人",
        containerCssClass: "search",
        maximumInputLength: 10,
        width: '100%',
        minimumInputLength: 0,
        tags: true,
        data: miku,
        matcher:
            function (params, data) {
                console.log(data)
                if ($.trim(params) === '') {
                    return data;
                }
                if (data.includes(params)) {
                    return data;
                }
                return null;
            }
    });

but it return me:
Blue
David
Judy
Kate
John
It only output the "text" properties, and it cannot output other properties(like "id").
I want to search using the id.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.0/select2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.13/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <select class="user"></select>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(function () {
      miku = [
        { id: 1, text: "Blue", note: "123" },
        { id: 12, text: "David" },
        { id: 3, text: "Judy" },
        { id: 4, text: "Kate" },
        { id: 5, text: "John" },
      ];
      $(".user").select2({
        language: 'zh-TW',
        width: '100%',
        maximumInputLength: 10,
        minimumInputLength: 0,
        tags: true,
        data: miku,
        matcher:
          function (params, data) {
            var term = params.term;
            console.log(data)
            if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
              return data;
            }
            if (data.id.includes(term)) {
              console.log(data.id);
              return data;
            }
            return null;
          }
      });
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>

This is the page I tested; it works fine. However, when added to the project, the output is different.
it can output otrher properties.
I also don't understand why the same code results in different outcomes.

you said it worked fine .. but I wonder how since you included jquery after select2 .. and more importantly you have 2 different versions of select2!! you should just remove the v3.5 being the very first line. In general you should look at the error in the console if you wish to find clues on what's going on and how to solve it
